# How to create a new folder, with Nautilus configured to view items as list

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

In Nautilus I clicked "*View items as a list*" because I prefer how it shows the files.

**Question**: How to create a new folder when there are more files than fit in the window?

Anywhere I click there is something under, that takes the context menu and does not propose folder creation:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The File menu still has the "New Folder" entry, and you can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

If you're using GNOME Shell, the hamburger menu (the three bars on the top right) has the relevant entry:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the "file" in the top bar. It has an option for adding a folder and it also lists the shortcuts too:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> for adding a folder
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> for adding a file.

Alternatives ...

- make the window larger so there is an empty line
- filter content so there are less items in the current window
- switch to another view

... and rightclick will have the option to add a folder.